# I have to create Temporary tables. I am getting this error "Table 'db1104107.temp' doesn't exist"

Tags: php

```
$query_createTemporaryTable = "
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE  `temporary2`(
    temporary_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
    ArtistName VARCHAR( 20 ) , NAMEOfTheDVD VARCHAR( 30 )
  )Engine = InnoDB
";
```

I used these commands within PHPmyadmin and it worked correctly. Its just not working in PHP code

```
$result_createtemptable = mysql_query($query_createTemporaryTable ); 

$query_insertintotable = "INSERT INTO temporary2 ( ArtistName, NAMEOfTheDVD) VALUES ( 'R', 'SHAWooSHANK')"; 

$result_insertintotable = mysql_query($query_insertintotable ) or die(mysql_error()); 

$query_selecttemptable = "SELECT ArtistName,NAMEOfTheDVD FROM temporary2"; 

$result_selecttemptable = mysql_query( $query_selecttemptable) or die(mysql_error()); 

while($row_selecttemptable = mysql_fetch_array($result_selecttemptable)){ 
      echo $row_selecttemptable(`ArtistName`, `NAMEOfTheDVD'); 

  } 


  mysql_close();

?>
```

here

Comment: Do You execute these commands within one request or not?

Comment: Your error code mentions table temp, however in your code that have syntax errors and no chance to execute, you are using temporary2. Please use actual code, otherwise it is extremely hard to help.